# Plotting multiple histograms on one graph based off number of columns in dataframe Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have sets of dataframes that I'm grouping in a function to be plotted based of `like` names using `.filter(like='some string')`.

My dataframes tend to look like this:

```
d = {'Upper Density': [1, 2, 4, 6], 'Lower Density': [3, 4, 7, 8], 'Mid Density': [6, 5, 7, 10], 'High Temperature' : [10, 11, 12, 10], 'Low Temperature' : [4, 5, 6, 7]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

variables = list(df.columns)
```

I filter by the likeness of the columns to one another, (ie: Density and Temperature), but obviously the length of each will differ (Density has 3 histograms to plot and Temperature only has 2).

I have a `list` of variable string names that I use to filter on called `variables` which just contains the names of the columns in `d`.

My code looks like this:

for var_name in variables:

```
df_var = (df.filter(like=str(var_name))).astype(float) # filter on each variable for comparison
n = len(df_var.columns) # get the length of each set of columns

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, n, sharex='col', sharey='row', figsize=(16,8)) # set the default axis parameters
axes = ax.ravel()

for i, j in zip(range(n), axes):

    # Plot Frequency
    j.hist([df_var.iloc[:,i-1], df_var.iloc[:,i]], alpha=0.4, bins=bin_size, color=colors)
    j.set_title(df_var.columns[i][:])
    j.legend(loc='best')
    j.grid(True)
```

When these iterate over they plot 2 of the same histograms side-by-side because the `subplots` have arguments `1` and `n`. But in order for me to iterate I don't see how I can get around using `subplots`.

I'd like the output to be that for each set of similar columns there is 1 histogram (ie: that Upper Density, Lower Density, and Mid Density are all plotted together but Upper and Lower Temperature are plotted together based off how many matches).

How can I change my code to get this?

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by replacing the entire loop with a simple `np.array()` call.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, n, sharex='col', sharey='row', figsize=(16,8)) # set the default axis parameters
axes = ax.ravel()

for i, j in zip(range(n), axes):
# Plot Frequency
j.hist([df_var.iloc[:,i-1], df_var.iloc[:,i]], alpha=0.4, bins=bin_size, color=colors)
j.set_title(df_var.columns[i][:])
j.legend(loc='best')
j.grid(True)
```

Was changed into:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(sharex='col', sharey='row', figsize=(14,8)) # set the default axis parameters

plt.hist(np.array(df_var), bins=bins, alpha=0.7)
plt.title(df_var.columns[i][:]+' with '+df_var.columns[i+1][:])
```